# How do I figure out how a given malware works?

Tags: virtual-machine, malware

I need to see the working of a malware (stuxnet) as a course reading assignment. I have its source code in C, but I don't know how to see its working. I though of running it in a virtual machine in Ubuntu but I am not sure if it will infect my computer or not.

How should I run, rather, test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too see how it works, you don't need to be an expert in C, but it will help if you are familiar with the language.

To test the file, compile it to a windows or linux binary and then run it from inside a virtual machine (VM). Malware can break out of the VM and infect the host machine, so backing up your data or using a separate computer might be a good idea.

If I recall correctly, stuxnet had a very specific start routine and wouldn't start unless a number of hardwareIDs existed.